# Why doesn't PHP prepared statements like my SQL dot notation?

Tags: php, prepared-statement

So, at first I was joining a lot of tables, and using aliases, but I simplified it to the following notation and it's give me this error.

> Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_param(): Number of variables doesn't match number of parameters in prepared statement in

```
$sql = "SELECT table.name FROM `table`";

if (!($stmt = $link->prepare($sql))) {
    echo "Prepare failed: (" . $link->errno . ") " . $link->error;
    die();
}

if (!$stmt->execute()) {
    echo "Execute failed: (" . $stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error."<br/>";
    die();
}

if (!$stmt->bind_param("s", $country)) {
    echo "Binding parameters failed: (" . $stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error;
    die();
}
```

If I attempt to wrap `table.name` with ticks, then I get this error:

```
Prepare failed: (1054) Unknown column 'venues.name' in 'field list'
```

Comment: Why do you believe this error has something to do with `table.name`? If you changed it to just `name` wouldn't you still get the same error because of the fact that you're trying to bind `$country` to a prepared statement in which no parameters exist?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no parameters, yet you're binding one.  Hence the "Number of variables doesn't match number of parameters in prepared statement"

```
table.name
```

is completely valid for a column name, though depending on the actual names, you may need to do something like:

```
`table`.`name`
```

What you might be looking for is:

```
$sql = "SELECT `table`.`name` FROM `table` WHERE country = ?";
```

Note though that really you should avoid backticks as you should avoid using reserved names for entities.